# Denying direct access to AWS S3 Object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, access-control

In a web application scenario, html5 `<video>` tag is used as follows:

```
<video src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/avideo.mp4">
  <source type="video/mp4">
    HTML5 Video is required
</video>
```

How can I stop somebody from directly accessing the video by copy-pasting `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/avideo.mp4` in a browser URL bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example on [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4) regarding restricting access to only requests that include a specific HTTP referrer.